# Try-catch not working

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, webclient

```
class XWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri Url)
    {
        var Request = base.GetWebRequest(Url);
        ...........
        return Request;
    }
}
```

Using:

```
try
{
    XWebClient Client = new XWebClient();
    Client.DownloadString(new Uri("badurl:100500"));
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("exception");
}
```

I was hoping to get a messagebox, but I get an unhandled exception. What am I doing wrong?

---

Exception:
System.NotSupportedexception

Message:
The URI prefix is not recognized

Trace:

```
   System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri, Boolean useUriBase)
   System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri)
   System.Net.WebClient.GetWebRequest(Uri address)
   XWebClient.GetWebRequest(Uri Url) в [path]\XWebClient.cs:строка 28
   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
```

Comment: **What does the error say**?

Comment: @Inisheer: He would have to be to get the code to compile in the first place.

Comment: upd: add message and trace

Comment: Describe the crash.  Are you running it under the debugger with "break on all managed exceptions" enabled?  In that case the debugger would break on the line that threw the exception *before* the handler runs.

Comment: @Ed S. Thank you, problem solved. It really has been configured to intercept exceptions.

Comment: Went ahead and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are running it under the debugger with "break on all managed exceptions" enabled.  If that is the case the debugger would break on the line that threw the exception before the handler runs. Your handler is still working, the debugger is just letting you inspect the error beforehand.